# How to use Pimple C Extension

Tags: php, silex, pimple

I have the Pimple C extension installed and in my *phpinfo()* i can see that the Pimple extension is active.

I also have *pimple/pimple* in my composer.json and the php package is loaded.

As far as i see they dont collide as i dont get any errors, but how do i know that the extension is in use?

When i have the Pimple C extension installed, do i still need the php Pimple package?
Will the C extension silently override the php class?

Is it common behaviour that php will first check if a class is present in php itself and then fallback to a php implementation?

Comment: I think if you install Pimple as a PHP extension, you don't need to get it throught *composer* anymore. Pimple's object became available as other extension you used to (PDO for instance ?). As far as I remember you don't need to load extension's class, and namespace is the root *\*

Comment: if i look at silex (dev-master) f.e., pimple is ofc in the composer.json and so the php class will be loaded. as pimple's namespace is in root would the php_ext pimple replace the php pimple?

Comment: I reformulate your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716313/priority-between-spl-autoload-register-and-extensions-function).

Comment: great thx, there is already an answer there, feel free to place an answer here, i will gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will use the extension's one.

This is because autoloading will only happen if you are attempting to access a class which does not already exist. Extension functions and classes will exist after PHP's startup meaning before the code starts to run.

(answers from [hek2mgl user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716384/2814253))