# Priority between spl_autoload_register and extension's function?

Tags: php, autoload, php-extension

I use [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage my dependencies and class loading. This tool uses `spl_autoload_register` function.

I would like to use a PHP's extension that provides some classes with same definition (name, namespacing, functionnalities) than others classes defined throught *composer*.

Which class will PHP load? The extension's one, or the autoload's one, or maybe the PHP's comportment is undefined?

Comment: a use case can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701331/how-to-use-pimple-c-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP will use the extension's one. This is because autoloading will only happen if you are attempting to access a class which does not already exist. Extension functions and classes will exist after PHP's startup meaning before the code starts to run.